# ZeroClipboard JavaScript library throws Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject while hovering on the flash object

Tags: javascript, flash, zeroclipboard

I am trying to copy content to clipboard using ZeroClipboard, it seems a good library. But I am getting the error 'Error calling method on NPObject.' when the copy button (a flash) is hovered.

Seems like a flash security problem. But I am able to load the flash content.

I want to apply this script on blogger .
I have hosted the zeroclipboard js and swf files and also the main.js on my googledrive account ..

my website is http://status4whatsapp.blogspot.in/

but when i am hovering on the copy button .... an error is coming "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject"

what should i do to solve this ?
the url of my main.js file is 
https://googledrive.com/host/0Bz3rjsXA3uvhMW9KbFEyYmFCb3c/blogger/whatsapp_status/main.js

Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't very clear as we can't understand what you are after if u don't post some code :-)

Comment: my website is on blogger http://status4whatsapp.blogspot.in/.
I am using this zeroclipboard script for this website to copy the post title and i am linking the ZeroClipboard.js , main.js and ZeroClipboard.swf from my google drive account .
but when i am clicking on the copy button , there is coming an error  "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. "

Comment: https://googledrive.com/host/0Bz3rjsXA3uvhMW9KbFEyYmFCb3c/blogger/whatsapp_status/main.js

this is the url to my main.js file ...
What should i add or modify in this file to run the script successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be running into [this issue](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/170).

Comment: I have seen that documentation but i am not getting much clear to that ...
My problem is that ...

 
my website is on blogger status4whatsapp.blogspot.in. I am using this zeroclipboard script for this website to copy the post title and i am linking the ZeroClipboard.js , main.js and ZeroClipboard.swf from my google drive account . but when i am clicking on the copy button , there is coming an error "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. "

Comment: https://googledrive.com/host/0Bz3rjsXA3uvhMW9KbFEyYmFCb3c/blogger/whatsapp_status/main.js 
this is the url to my main.js file ... What should i add or modify in this file to run the script successfully ?